# PHP: Possible to use an array of strings to generate the keys of a returned array?

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

In my CodeIgniter app, I've got lots of model methods for fetching rows from the database. Sometime, I have multiple methods, with virtually the same database query, but package the returned results in an array with a different index structure to serve the view more efficiently, and to prevent myself from re-looping through the same data. For example:

This one just returns a non-associate array of resulting $rows:

```
public function get_rows($where = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select('Table1.field_1, Table2.field_2, Table3.field_3, etc.');
    $this->db->from('Table1');
    $this->db->join('Table2', 'etc');
    $this->db->join('Table3', 'etc');
    $this->build_where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

But this one, uses a bunch of fields as multi-dimensional indexes for those rows:

```
public function get_rows($where = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select('Table1.field_1, Table2.field_2, Table3.field_3, etc.');
    $this->db->from('Table1');
    $this->db->join('Table2', 'etc');
    $this->db->join('Table3', 'etc');
    $this->build_where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $rows[$row['field_1']][$row['field_2']][$row['field_3']] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Is there a way to pass an array (of any length) of strings to this method and have it be used to generate that index structure?

For example, if the function was called with this second argument:

```
 get_rows(NULL, array('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3'))
```

It would use this index structure inside the `foreach`:

```
 $rows[$row['field_1']][$row['field_2']][$row['field_3']] = $row;
```

And the output would be:

```
Array
(
    [field_1 value] => Array
        (
            [field_2 value] => Array
                (
                    [field_3 value] => Array
                        (
                            [field_1] => field_1 value
                            [field_2] => field_2 value
                            [field_3] => field_3 value
                        )

                    [field_3 value] => Array
                        (
                            [field_1] => field_1 value
                            [field_2] => field_2 value
                            [field_3] => field_3 value
                        )

                    [field_3 value] => Array
                        (
                            [field_1] => field_1 value
                            [field_2] => field_2 value
                            [field_3] => field_3 value
                        )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But if the function was called with only a single item in the second argument:

```
 get_rows(NULL, array('field_3'))
```

It would return this structure:

```
 $rows[$row['field_3']] = $row;
```

And thus this output:

```
Array
(
    [field_3 value] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => field_1 value
            [field_2] => field_2 value
            [field_3] => field_3 value
        )

    [field_3 value] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => field_1 value
            [field_2] => field_2 value
            [field_3] => field_3 value
        )

    [field_3 value] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => field_1 value
            [field_2] => field_2 value
            [field_3] => field_3 value
        )
    )
)
```

And lastly, if the second argument was empty, it would use no indexes:

```
 $rows[] = $row;
```

And thus this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => field_1 value
            [field_2] => field_2 value
            [field_3] => field_3 value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => field_1 value
            [field_2] => field_2 value
            [field_3] => field_3 value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => field_1 value
            [field_2] => field_2 value
            [field_3] => field_3 value
        )
    )
)
```

Obviously, I could just pass in a string as the second argument and use a switch/case/if to arrange the indexes accordingly, but if this could be done safely and efficiently, it seems like a great way to have fewer, more flexible model/database methods.

P.S. I do not want to use eval() for safety/security reasons.

Comment: `$rows[] = array_combine($secondArgument, $row);`

Comment: But that won't be multi-dimensional? And it'll turn all of my database data into keys?

Comment: What do you mean "won't be multidimensional"... have you tried it? have you looked at what the `array_combine()` function actually does?

Comment: A multi-dimensional array is an array inside an array (or deeper). Of course I've read the documentation for array_combine. Thanks for asking. I'm not interested in altering the keys or values of $row. I just wish to nest the $row array inside other arrays which use the passed arguments as keys/indexes.

Comment: Well that line of code that I posted will generate a 2-d array (2 dimensions), the top level enumerated, and the second level for each row is associative, based on the key names that you have entered..... if that isn't what you want, then I suggest that you improve your question by posting an example of what you expect to see returned from the function

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added the sample outputs now.